# Actualización de un RecyclerView

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, aplicación-movil

Estoy desarrollando un buscador de usuarios para mi aplicación en android studio con el lenguaje programación Java.

Actualmente mi buscador se muestra en un BottomSheetDialog el cual funciona de la siguiente manera

Este sería el método que detecta los cambios en la query o palabras que se ingresan en el buscador

```
searchUsers.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                searchFirestore(newText, nousersearch);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Y este el método que recibe esos cambios y ejecuta en base a ellos

```
private void searchFirestore(String search, TextView nouserfinded) {

        List<Pruebauser> pu = new ArrayList<>();
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("googleU").orderBy("nombre", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    Db_login user = doc.toObject(Db_login.class);


                    pu.add(new Pruebauser(user.getNombre(), user.getImgUrl(), user.getTipo()));


                }

                List<Pruebauser> coincidentes = new ArrayList<>();


                for (Pruebauser pruebauser : pu) {
                    if (pruebauser.getNombre().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains(search.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT))) {
                        coincidentes.add(pruebauser);
                    }
                }


                if (!coincidentes.isEmpty()) {
                    nouserfinded.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    for (Pruebauser coincidente : coincidentes) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Nombre con: " + coincidente.getNombre());
                        System.out.println("Nombre: " + coincidente.getNombre());
                    }

                } else {
                    nouserfinded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    System.out.println("No se encontraron coincidencias con '" + search + "'.");
                    Log.d(TAG, "No se encontraron coincidencias con '" + search + "'.");
                }




                AdaptadorUserTeams adaptadorUserTeams = new AdaptadorUserTeams(coincidentes, textNoUsers);
                reciclerSearch.setAdapter(adaptadorUserTeams);
                reciclerSearch.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL));
                adaptadorUserTeams.notifyDataSetChanged();





            }
        });




    }
```

como pueden ver primero obtengo todos los usuarios en que hay en la base de datos y los guardo en una lista, y luego creo otra lista para almacenar los que coinciden con lo que el usuario está buscando, esto funciona a la perfección.

Ahora surgue que quiero que al momento de yo precionar algun item que ya está cargado en el RecyclerView por medio de la lista donde se almacenan los usuarios que coinciden con la búsqueda, otro RecyclerView en el mismo BottomSheetDialog obtenga ese usuario seleccionado y lo muestre al instante o lo cargue al momento que se hace la selección